# Is $A∩B^c∩C^c = A-[A∩(B∪C)] $ ? (Set Theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm studying set operations.

The example problem is:

Find a simpler expression of $[(A∪B)∩(A∪C)∩(B^c∩C^c)]$ assuming all three sets intersect.

The answer I came up with is $A∩B^c∩C^c$, while the solution given is $A-[A∩(B∪C)]$. Are these equivalent? If so, is one answer better than the other and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me what you have done before I answer?

Comment: I drew a Venn diagram with sets A, B, and C intersecting. The part I have shaded to represent the expression above includes all events that occur in A, but not in B nor C.

Comment: Do not use diagrams. Prove it. Refer to my "Hint."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove with $x\in[(A∪B)∩(A∪C)∩(B^c∩C^c)]$ and use the definitions of each operation. Use the complement of $A$ and $B$ with respect to the universal set $H.$

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if I understand how to do this, so please bear with me.  

So A∪B = {x|x∈A or x∈B}  
and A∪C = {x|x∈A or x∈C}  
I think that means (A∪B)∩(A∪C) = {x|x∈A or (x∈B & x∈C)}  
  
Then Bc∩Cc = {x|x∉B & x∉C}  
So [(A∪B)∩(A∪C)∩(Bc∩Cc)] = {x|[x∈A or (x∈B & x∈C)] & (x∉B & x∉C)}  
But x won't occur in B & C if x∉B & x∉C,  
so [(A∪B)∩(A∪C)∩(Bc∩Cc)] = {x|x∈A & (x∉B & x∉C)}

I'm not sure how to use the complement of A and B with respect to H... I think I'm missing something.

Comment: No, you did well. It is good. For example, $B^c$ just means that $x\in{H}$ and $x\notin{B}.$ That is the formal definition of a complement. Use my hint as a start for all your proofs, assuming that $x\in \ \text{"some set"}.$ Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Okay, so I do understand what the complement is. I just don't know where I would use the complement of A in solving this.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now that I've reviewed De Morgan's Laws and the definition of relative complements...  A-[A∩(B∪C)] = A∩[A∩(B∪C)]c = A∩[Ac∪(B∪C)c] = A∩(B∪C)c = A∩Bc∩Cc !